# Error al redireccionar a https por htaccess en subdominio

Tags: .htaccess, https

Saludos de nuevo compañeros,

Tengo un proyecto que debe funcionar bajo https, todo funciona bien cuando uso el dominio principal, pero tengo un subdominio para test, en el que no funciona la redirección, se queda en un ciclo, ya investigue y probe de diferentes formas pero no se como solucionarlo, mi htaccess esta asi

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =test.proyecto.local
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,QSA,R=permanent]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1
```

El problema es que si me redirige a https, pero se queda haciendo esta redireccion infinitamente, alguna forma de solucionarlo?

Comment: Prueba acceder a alguna dirección que no sea la página principal. De este modo me aseguro de que no tengas el problema en el código de la página. Por ejemplo a: sub.dominio.com/contacto y asegúrate de que el archivo que estás editando (.htaccess) esté en la ruta principal de la carpeta del subdominio,y no fuera de este.

Comment: Gracias por resopnder Brahim, he revisado el codigo tambien y dentro del codigo hay redirecciones que al parecer me estan dando problema, lo que sucede es que este es un proyecto de la empresa donde trabajo y no inicie yo el proyecto. Pero al parecer ya no es problema del htaccess, voy a revisar eso y al resolver, les comento, gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con este:

```
RewriteEngine On

#Redireccionar a https cuando tiene www
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

#Redireccionar a https con www cuando no tiene https ni www
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule .* https://www.tuweb.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

#Redireccionar a www cuando tiene https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule .* https://www.tuweb.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Gracias por responder, ya hice la prueba y no funciona, con dominio www.midominio.com, funciona, pero en el subdominio no, que seria algo asi: test.midominio.com, en ese caso se queda en un ciclo

Comment: Lo que pasa es que en el subdominio debes crear el otro archivo `.htaccess` y allí pegar el direccionamiento ejemplo `RewriteRule .* https://www.subdominio.dominioo.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]`

Comment: Y por cierto, si lo tengo asi, un htaccess diferente en cada directorio

Answer (score 0):

Puedes concatenar un `RewriteCond` con `REQUEST_SCHEME`, para comprobar que no estés ya en `HTTPS`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =test.proyecto.local
**RewriteCond %{REQUEST_SCHEME} !https**
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,QSA,R=permanent]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1
```

Comment: Me da este error: AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

Comment: Ese error es por la última redirección:

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1

Tienes que excepcionar  el /index.php . Quedaría:

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "!index.php"
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1

Answer (score 0):

gracias por su ayuda, logré resolver el problema que tenía. Ya no fue necesario agregar nuevas reglas, con la regla de redirección de dominio principal a https fue suficiente.

Lo que sucede es que como es un sistema que yo no cree de 0, pertenece a la empresa donde trabajo, me puse a revisar el código internno mas detalladamente y encontré redirecciones que al final provocaban la redirección infinita, corregido eso, ya todo funcionó bien.

Gracias!!